# Spring Boot 2.0 can't connect to ElasticSearch 5.5.0 - NoNodeAvailableException

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I was following a lot of examples / documentations but can't figure out how to connect from Spring Boot 2.0 to ElasticSearch 5.5.0 using spring data elastic and TransportClient. I always gets NoNodeAvailableException when trying to connect to elasticsearch.

My code is following:

*pom.xml*

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

*config class*

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.demo")
public class EsConfig {

    @Value("${elasticsearch.host}")
    private String EsHost;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.port}")
    private int EsPort;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.clustername}")
    private String EsClusterName;

    @Bean
    public Client client() throws Exception {

        Settings esSettings = Settings.builder()
                .put("cluster.name", EsClusterName)
                .build();

        TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(esSettings)
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(EsHost), Integer.valueOf(EsPort)));
        return client;
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
    }
}
```

*application.properties*

```
elasticsearch.clustername = elasticsearch
elasticsearch.host = localhost
elasticsearch.port = 9300
```

As i run the application I get an error:

```
failed to load elasticsearch nodes : org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{ru3fMzoqTQygBpT5C6KXXw}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}]
```

My elasticsearch is running in docker container

```
run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 --name elasticsearch -d --network mynetwork elasticsearch:5.5.0
```

Comment: You should use the rest client instead. That's what is recommended now by elastic team itself

Comment: Java High Level REST Client was released in the version 5.6.0 of Elasticsearch. I need to connect to older version 5.5.0

Comment: The high level yes. But you can use the lower level and the query builders (and use toString, in order to pass them in the lower level). I've done this and it's very convenient

Comment: I guess with lower level I can't use spring-data-elasticsearch which would be much appreciated... :-(

Comment: for me its working by just using a property without java config: `spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=localhost:9300`. Also be sure that elastic is reachable on localhost from the docker container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in docker container itself. To connect to docker container from java you need to set **http.host** to 0 **transport.host** to 0 **disable xpack** security and **disable sniffing**
If anyone else struggle here's solution:

```
docker network create mynetwork --driver=bridge
docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "http.host=0.0.0.0" -e "transport.host=0.0.0.0" -e "xpack.security.enabled=false" -d --name thesiselasticsearch -d --network mynetwork docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.5.0
docker run -d --network mynetwork -e ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://thesiselasticsearch:9200 --name thesiskibana -p 5601:5601 kibana:5.5.0
```

and configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.demo")
public class EsConfig {

    @Value("${elasticsearch.host}")
    private String EsHost;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.port}")
    private int EsPort;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.clustername}")
    private String EsClusterName;

    @Bean
    public Client client() throws Exception {

        Settings esSettings = Settings.builder()
                .put("cluster.name", "docker-cluster")
                .put("client.transport.sniff", false)
                .build();


        TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(esSettings)
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9300));
        return client;
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this is what solved it for me:

This was my first issue:

*debug log:*

```
Parameter 0 of method elasticsearchTemplate in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - buildClient: defined by method 'buildClient' in class path resource [nl/dummypackage/config/ElasticsearchConfig.class]
    - elasticsearchClient: defined by method 'elasticsearchClient' in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.class]
```

I removed my *ElasticsearchConfig* class  and
add this property to

*application.properties*

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=localhost:9300
```

Next issue:  missing authentication token

*debug log:*

```
org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [elasticsearch-docker-single-node][172.19.0.2:9300][cluster:monitor/nodes/liveness]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSecurityException: missing authentication token for action [cluster:monitor/nodes/liveness]
```

For now, I solved it by disabling xpack.security:

*elasticsearch.yml*

```
xpack.security.enabled: false
```

Comment: I'm using ES remote server that has username and password to log in, any idea how to put them in the properties file